# Authenticated Flatpak repo

Tags: linux, flatpak

Would it be possible to have a password protected flatpak repository?

I'm developing a commercial software and at the moment we're supporting only Ubuntu 20.04 and we host an authenticated apt repository.
I'd like to support more systems, eg: RHEL based, SUSE based, and all Debian based distributions, but one requirement is being able to stop ugrading the software for certain users, should the need arise.

With apt it's easy: a repo is just a directory structure and a http server.
Once a user is deleted they can't download any new updates, but I couldn't find anything about an authenticated self hosted Flatpak repo...

Comment: Another format like AppImage might be simpler, since then they'd likely just be using their browser to download the app, and then you can stick any common web authentication mechanism on it.

Comment: Of course, but I'd liked something a little more integrated with the rest of the system

Answer (score 1):

Flatpak repos are also just https-accesssed archives.

So, authenticate your subscribers by giving them unique URLs. That can be implemented by simple means like a symlink that you allow your web server to follow to the actual repo on disk.

Network Security-wise, that's as good as any Debian repo (or any other website) behind basic auth over http over TLS: the server, in this  case the secret part of the URL, is transmitted only encrypted. Practically, since that URL is visible on the client, it gives all people who use flatpak on the end machine knowledge of that secret.

Comment: So, let's say that I give our customer Alice a unique ID, eg: AB-001-24 - 
If I add that ID to the url of her flatpak it'll "act" like our current authentication?
eg: http://updates.myproject.com/linux/AB-001-24 - 

And if I disable that URL they can't download upgrades any longer, right?

Comment: Yep, and disabling that ID would be as hard as deleting a single symlink. (If course, you'd use a longer and unpredictable thing instead of your customer ID, or else people would just guess other customers' IDs. A random string of 32 characters would do, for example)